# NVIDIA CUDA 5.5 Compatible graphics hardware error

Tags: cuda, nvidia, incompatibility

I have following machine.

```
1.Dell XPS 8700 
2.Intel Core i7-4790
3.16GB RAM
4.NVIDIA GetForce GTX 750TI 2GB with NVIDIA GRAPHICS Driver 347.09
5.Windows 8.1 64-bit
```

I am trying to install CUDA 5.5 Desktop since the latest does not support DESKTOP I even tried it and found the same error.
[image: The Graphics could not find compatible hardware.....]

**It says that Grahpics could not find compatible hardware. you may wish to continue but you will not be able to run CUDA applications.**

Please guide me how to correct this error I wanna use CUDA for development purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct.  The CUDA 5.5 installer does not contain a compatible driver for your GPU.  If you really want to use CUDA 5.5, then continue on past this screen.

Deselect the option in a subsequent screen to install the GPU driver, but install the toolkit (and samples, if you wish).

The driver that is currently on your machine and compatible with GTX 750 Ti (347.09) will work with CUDA 5.5

I'm not sure why you would want to install such an old version of CUDA.  CUDA 6.5 production release is currently available and CUDA 7.0 RC is also available to registered developers.  The installer for either one should have a driver that is compatible with your GTX 750 Ti.  However, in either case my recommendation would be the same - leave your existing driver intact, and deselect the option in the CUDA installer to install a driver.

Comment: I did not choose new version coz there was not desktop support only notebook.

Comment: CUDA 6.5 has desktop versions available, right [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Comment: will same problem that I posted here will occur on CUDA 6.5 or you are not sure? also the link you posted has DESKTOP support for windows7 only NOT for windows8.1.

Comment: I already said in my answer that CUDA 6.5 should have a driver built into it that recognizes your GPU.  But you can deselect that driver and keep your 349.09 driver.  That's what I would do.